# How to import classes from another Eclipse CDT project into my current project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have one eclipse CDT project (let's call it Project A) where I have a class (a .cpp and .h file) which is a data structure I have been working on. Basically Project A has this class and some other classes to test the data structure. Now I am building another project (let's call it Project B) where I will be using the same data structure. Since I do not want to copy paste, and also since it is ongoing work (I am likely to change the data structure class and I don't to keep updating code in 2 copies as I make changes), I would like to just include that class in my current project. How do I do this so that when I change the class in Project A, the same class imported in Project B automatically changes ? I googled around a bit, and I cant use options like CMake. For compiling and running the code, I do not use Eclipse. I have written my own make file and run it on the terminal. Oh btw, if it was not clear earlier this is on Eclipse CDT (i.e., for C++).

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.